# ProgressDialog does not disappear after executing dismiss, hide or cancel?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have an Overlay extension which has 2 dialogs as private attributes - one Dialog and one ProgressDialog. After clicking on the Overlay in the MapView, the Dialog object appears. When the user clicks a button in the Dialog it disappears and the ProgressDialog is shown. Simultaneously a background task is started by notifying a running Service. When the task is done, a method (buildingLoaded) in the Overlay object is called to switch the View and to dismiss the ProgressDialog. The View is being switched, the code is being run (I checked with the debugger) but the ProgressDialog is not dismissed. I also tried hide() and cancel() methods, but nothing works. Can somebody help me?
Android version is 2.2

Here is the code:

```
public class LODOverlay extends Overlay implements OnClickListener {



private Dialog overlayDialog;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

       ..............


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

                   .......

        final Context ctx = view.getContext();
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        ListView lv = new ListView(ctx);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.layout.layerlist, names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        final LODOverlay obj = this;
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                String name = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        Intent getFloorIntent = new Intent(Map.RENDERER);
        getFloorIntent.putExtra("type", "onGetBuildingLayer");
        getFloorIntent.putExtra("id", name);
        view.getContext().sendBroadcast(getFloorIntent);
        overlayDialog.dismiss();

        obj.waitingForLayer = name;

        progressDialog.show(ctx, "Loading...", "Wait!!!");


            }
        });

    .......
}


public void buildingLoaded(String id) {
    if (null != this.progressDialog) {
        if (id.equals(this.waitingForLayer)) {
            this.progressDialog.hide();
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

    ............

            Map.flipper.showNext();  // changes the view
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't show us where you create or show the overlayDialog. Are you sure overlayDialog is referencing the same dialog that's showing?

Comment: You're also a little vague about threading. When you start a background task, are you using AsyncTask? Is the `AsyncTask` where `buildingLoaded` is invoked? That wouldn't work.

Comment: overlayDialog is working fine - the progressDialog is the problem.

Comment: OK, here is the basic structure of the project:
The main activity (MapActivity) starts one Service to run as a background task. When the user interacts with the map, some messages are sent to the Service via Intents and some XML data is loaded and processed. After the data is processed, an Intent is sent to the main Activity which finds the Overlay and calls the buildingLoaded() method of that overlay. I am almost sure, that the right object is referenced, since I have only one right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but the method you are calling on `ProgressDialog` is `static`, but you are calling it on an instance of the class.  Here's the method definition:

```
public static ProgressDialog show (Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message)
```

As you can see, the method **returns** a `ProgressDialog`, it does not perform the `show` operation on your instance of the class.  Update your code to use one of these:

```
progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
progressDialog.setMessage("Wait!!!");
progressDialog.show();
```

or

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Loading...", "Wait!!!");
```

Answer (score 2):

ProgressDialog.show(...) methods do in fact perform a show() on the dialog before returning it.  Here is Android.jar source:

```
public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
        boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

All the overloads of this method refer to this one.